# Resize buttons of a Spinbox

Tags: tkinter, button, resize, size

Is there a way to resize the buttons used in the SpinboxWidget (Tkinter)? I'm trying to build a touchscreen optimized GUI. I couldn't find any suitable option in the docs but maybe there is an other way or I just didn't see the option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know way to access `Spinbox` buttons, but you can use `Control` widget from [tkinter.tix](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/tkinter.tix.html#tkinter.tix.Control):

```
import tkinter.tix as tix
root = tix.Tk()
c = tix.Control(root)
c.pack()
decr = c.subwidget('decr')
incr = c.subwidget('incr')
decr['height'] = incr['height'] = 100
decr['width'] = incr['width'] = 100
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I use this in a class? Is it possible to combine it with ttk-widgets in the same frame, which is placed in a tkinter-root window?

Comment: What means "in a class"? You can mix `tix` with `ttk`, but `tix` widgets remain ugly (but `root` must be `tix.Tk`).